# Kurento : custom module error while adding "properties"

Tags: kurento

I'm trying to add "properties" in my custom module by using the following code

In my *.kdm.json file:

```
"properties": [
{
  "name": "params",
  "doc": "set params",
  "type": "String"
}
]
```

Im my .hpp file

```
virtual std::string getParams();
virtual void setParams (std::string params);
```

In my .cpp file

```
void myCustomFilterImpl::setParams (std::string params)
{
    //code here
}

std::string myCustomFilterImpl::getParams ()
{
  return params.c_str();
}
```

I'm getting following error while running `debuild`

```
 error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘kurento::module::mycustomfilter::myCustomFilterImpl’ return new myCustomFilterImpl (conf, mediaPipeline);

..... note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘kurento::module::mycustomfilter::myCustomFilterImpl’:   class myCustomFilterImpl:public FilterImpl, public virtual myCustomFilter
         ^
.... note:  virtual void kurento::module::mycustomfilter::myCustomFilter::setParams(const string&)
   virtual void setParams (const std::string &params) = 0;
                ^
... error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
       }
       ^
```

Is there anything that I'm missing here to add in my custom module code ?

`properties` is working fine for my other custom module but I don't know how I'm getting this error in this custom module.

Comment: looks like adding the `"properties"` in the `kdm.json` file is making the class abstract, any ideas what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the method is declared like this by the template:

```
virtual void setParams (const std::string &params);
```

But you are implementing it like this:

```
virtual void setParams (std::string params);
```

Note the difference in `params` declararion (`&` and `const`)